# Installing SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012 R2 without internet connection

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2014 onto a 2012 R2 box which does not have an internet connection (and for security reasons, I'm not allowed to give it one). I didn't think this would be an issue, so I downloaded the installation media (along with .NET 3.5) onto a USB stick and installed from there (specifying DO NOT CHECK FOR UPDATES).

The Database Engine Services failed, with the logs suggesting that it is due to being unable to check for updates. I manually downloaded and installed SP1 & 2 along with the cumulative update for SQL Server 2014, and tried again. The issue still persists. I am pretty much out of ideas at this point, and googling it doesn't seem to return much information. The exact error I am getting is below.

```
    Product Update Status:
  User selected not to include product updates.
  Error message:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CancelException
    Message: 
        Setup is not able to find a server to download product updates because the operation is cancelled.
    HResult : 0x84b70642
        FacilityCode : 1207 (4b7)
        ErrorCode : 1602 (0642)
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSetupSearchEngine.SelectServer()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSetupSearchEngine.SearchUpdates()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.SearchUpdatesAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to run the install from the USB stick, what happens if you copy the installation files to a local disk, such as C:\ or D:\ on the server and run the install from there? Same error?

Comment: check the installation media itself, sounds like its possibly corrupted..https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11533